# How important is the seemandhan function and is it OK to be avoided?

Tags: vedas, puranas, advaita, vaishnavism, smarta

I'd like to understand a few points on the Seemandham function.

1. How important is it to the mother and the baby? Is it OK for the function to be avoided overall?
2. How important is the Udhagha Shanthi ritual in the Seemandham?
3. How important is the Nandhi ritual in the Seemandham? I've seen this ritual only be performed by Smarthas and not vaishnavas. So, it is OK to skip the Nandhi function? Does it have any bad impact if skipped?

Please let me know from your experience and knowledge.

Thank you.

Comment: Naandhi shraddha is a a ritual done to get the blessings of one's ancestors which usually preceedes the tbd samskara .If this is not a part of your custom, it is better to simply carry fwd whatever is followed in your lineage.

Comment: Udhaka Shanti also preceedes most of the auspicious samskaras, in which vedic mantras are recited and devatas are invoked in kalash containing water, which is later sprinkled onto those concerned with the samskara.

Comment: If your family follows , Apastamba sutra, seemanthonayana is done on prathame Garbe only (first conception) fourth or eighth month, It is done for the protection of the mother and child.Dhaatha is said to be the devata invoked for protection(Afaik). Again, the details depend on Gruhya sutras followed. Any vedic priest/upadhyaya is adept on samskara s who is usually trusted for any guidance

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But could you please clear my other questions mentioned in my question?

Comment: IMO, If samskaaras are valued, its rather better to harness the benefit of performing it, than skipping the same..yet it depends on ones viability over several factors that aid the function.. , Regarding a ritual (say Naandhi) which is not a part of your family tradition, Only a Vedic officiator (of your custom) is the authoritative person to give you the right guidance..Certain questions seem to be beyond the scope of this forum.